# Newbie python question about classes: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot get this Python assignment to work as I expect it to.  Thus far, all the explanations I have gotten has not made sense to me.

Code:

```
class attribute: #Mandatory may not be changed
    def __init__(self,Input_1,Input_2):
        self.info_1= Input_1
        self.info_2= Input_2

def Lister(List1,List2): #Mandatory Function may not be removed
    List= []
    for x in List1:
        List.append(attribute(List1,List2))
    return List


def Checker(List): #Mandatory Function may not be removed
    Awnser=input("What is"+List.info_1) 
    if Awnser != List.info_2 :
        print("Incorrect")
    else:
       print("Correct")

List_a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
List_b=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

Checker(Lister(List_a,List_b))
```

The code is meant to take `List_a` and `List_b` and ask the user what the corresponding value would be in the other list. 
However, I keep running into this error, and don't know why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 24, in <module>
    Checker(Lister(List_a,List_b))
  File "so.py", line 14, in Checker
    Awnser=input("What is"+List.info_1) 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'info_1'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Has no attribute *what*? And *where* is this error happening? If you get an error, you need to show the whole thing.

Comment: You need `Awnser=input("What is"+str(List[0].info_1))` and `if Awnser != str(List[0].info_2) :`. That will work (or, at least, it then allowed me to input a list and compared it to the original), but it's really not nice code.

Comment: When getting into OOP, it's really easy to tie yourself up in knots (you seem to have gone off-course in this example). I think it would be worth just following some tutorials in the beginning before you make things more confused

Answer (score 2):

`List` is of type `list`.  It does not have any attribute `info_1`.  However, `List` has a single element of type `attribute` ... and *that* object will have an attribute named `info_1`.

I recommend that you use more descriptive variable names, and *especially* avoid using names of existing language concepts.  Using the class-type name `List` as a list *object* is a little flaky; using the concept `attribute` as the name of a class is outright misleading.

I suggest also that you try incremental programming: implement just *one* tiny step at a time.  Make sure you know how to manipulate that before you add more code.  here, you've piled on two or three new ideas before doing any testing, which likely adds to your confusion.

Your current code needs two small changes to get output without error:

```
def Checker(List): #Mandatory Function may not be removed
    Awnser=input("What is"+str(List.info_1))
```

and

```
Checker(Lister(List_a,List_b)[0])
```

This gives you the original list as output:

```
What is[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```